# Is there an option to add CSS3 features to old browsers which are not supported by Modernizr?

Tags: html, css, modernizr

1 - Did Modernizr only detects what features are supported by the browser ?

2 - Did Modernizr it able to add features to browser which not exist in old browser ?

3 - did there is option/solution to add features of css3 to old browser which not supported not related to Modernizr  ?

Many Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think so.
2. Depends on Modernizr version ( talking about respond.js )
3. There are. Take a look at http://caniuse.com You can find there resources for different properties

Comment: How can I use with properties perspective to all broweser acording to  [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com)

Comment: With Modernizr you check if feature is available, if not, you use some  polyfills to make it working on your browser. For example border radius for old IE use css3pie: .noborderradius .box { behavior: url(path/to/PIE.htc); }  Something like that